# SQLite error with grabbing data from a table

Tags: python, sqlite

Sorry if I post a picture instead of the code in here, been a day.

So I am attempting to use this function to save a string and an integer value for the username and  a points value (it’s for a dumb discord bot).

So the issue is that I’m trying to check if this saved data exists already, but for some reason I get the error “none type” is non scriptable. I am trying to check if it is none or not and if it is, make an entry, if not update the entry.

I’ve been trying to do this for days. Sorry if I am confusing and if you need more information pls ask questions! Adhd is bad today so I’m a little scattered but I NEED ANSWERS[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sriSy.png)

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM nice_words')
niceWords_temp = cur.fetchall()
niceWords = [''.join(item) for item in niceWords_temp]

cur.execute('SELECT MeanWords FROM mean_words')
meanWords_temp = cur.fetchall()
meanWords = [''.join(item) for item in meanWords_temp]

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM nice_responses')
responseSecretionNice_temp = cur.fetchall()
responseSecretionNice = [''.join(item) for item in 
responseSecretionNice_temp]

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mean_responses')
responseSecretionMean_temp = cur.fetchall()
responseSecretionMean = [''.join(item) for item in responseSecretionMean_temp]

anus = discord.Client()

#saving user data
temp_adore_points = 0
temp_nice_tokens = 0
temp_mean_tokens = 0

def saving_the_user_data_for_messaging(user, isNice=True):
    #casting user as a string 
    user = str(user)

    
    temp_user = cur.execute('SELECT user FROM saving_user_data WHERE User = (?)', (user, )).fetchone()[0]
    print(temp_user)
    #checking if the user was saved before
    if temp_user is None:
        adorePoints = 0
    
        if isNice:
            adorePoints = adorePoints + 1
        else:
            adorePoints = adorePoints - 1
    
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO saving_user_data (User, KevinsAdorationPoints) values (?, 0, 0, 0)', (user,))
        #insert in one, update in another
    else:
        temp_adore_points = cur.execute('SELECT KevinsAdorationPoints FROM saving_user_data WHERE User = (?)', (user, )).fetchone()
        adorePoints = temp_adore_points[0]#make this a mofocin integer somehow
    
        if isNice:
            adorePoints = adorePoints + 1
        else:
            adorePoints = adorePoints - 1
    
        cur.execute('UPDATE saving_user_data SET KevinsAdorationPoints = ? WHERE User = ?', (adorePoints, user, ))
    

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM saving_user_data')
    print(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: The circled code is the problem children

Comment: This discord bot is also what I’m using to learn data and python for work in the future so I’m still learning

Comment: You can post the code as usual text. Someone will do the formatting.

Comment: in saving_the_user_data_for_messaging
    temp_user = cur.execute('SELECT User FROM saving_user_data WHERE User = ?', (user, )).fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable